# Django OperationalError Unknown Column

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to create a CRUD using Django Rest Framework and a MySQL database. I use sqlclient as connector for the MySQL connection. 
The problem is when I want to do request, it always throws me the next error.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'author_id' in 'post'")
```

I don't have declared `author_id` variable in nowhere neither in my code or in the database, I don't know why django is saying that the author_id column is required.

The model that I'm using is this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateField(default = timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", db_column='author', on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'post'
```

The serializer looks like this:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['post_id', 'title', 'text', 'created_date']
```

And the view set like this:

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        #permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly  #Permission for unauthorized GET requests
        IsGetOrIsAuthenticated   # Custom permission for unauthorized GET requests
    ]
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        print(self.request.user.id)
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user.id)
```

I really not understand why is creating `author_id` if is nowhere in the code or the database. Why is creating it? What I have to do to the app to work?

Comment: `author_id` is the internal name for the foreign key field. To your problem: did you create and run all migrations?

Comment: @KlausD. yeah, I did the makemigrations and migrate commands

Answer (score 0):

author column you are referring as foreign key to the User table, which django 
stores this author column as author_id as internal field as it refers to the pk (id) of the User table.

Try   def perform_create(self, serializer):
        print(self.request.user.id)
        serializer.save(author_id=self.request.user.id)